# How to save and load selected and all variables in tensorflow 2.0 using tf.train.Checkpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How do I save selected variables in tensorflow 2.0 shown below in a file and load them into some defined variables in another code using tf.train.Checkpoint?

```
class manyVariables:
    def __init__(self):
        self.initList = [None]*100
        for i in range(100):
            self.initList[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([5,5]))
        self.makeSomeMoreVariables()

    def makeSomeMoreVariables(self):
        self.moreList = [None]*10
        for i in range(10):
            self.moreList[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([3,3]))

    def saveVariables(self):
        # how to save self.initList's 3,55 and 60th elements and self.moreList's 4th element
```

Also, please show how to save all the variables and reload using tf.train.Checkpoint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. I assume you have read the information on [checkpoints in 2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/checkpoints). If you create a [`tf.train.Checkpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint) for the specific variables that you want it should work, right? Or, what is it that prevents you from doing that?

Comment: I don't understand the above official link, it's too complex. Also, I don't get why each tf tutorial needs to be written for keras crap. I would love it if you can simply save the above 3 variables and restore. And also, save all 110 of them and restore using tf.train.Checkpoint IN A SIMPLE WAY UNLIKE DOCS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can create a [`tf.train.Checkpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint) object specifically for the variables that you want to save and restore. See the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class manyVariables:
    def __init__(self):
        self.initList = [None]*100
        for i in range(100):
            self.initList[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([5,5]))
        self.makeSomeMoreVariables()
        self.ckpt = self.makeCheckpoint()

    def makeSomeMoreVariables(self):
        self.moreList = [None]*10
        for i in range(10):
            self.moreList[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([3,3]))

    def makeCheckpoint(self):
        return tf.train.Checkpoint(
            init3=self.initList[3], init55=self.initList[55],
            init60=self.initList[60], more4=self.moreList[4])

    def saveVariables(self):
        self.ckpt.save('./ckpt')

    def restoreVariables(self):
        status = self.ckpt.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('.'))
        status.assert_consumed()  # Optional check

# Create variables
v1 = manyVariables()
# Assigned fixed values
for i, v in enumerate(v1.initList):
    v.assign(i * tf.ones_like(v))
for i, v in enumerate(v1.moreList):
    v.assign(100 + i * tf.ones_like(v))
# Save them
v1.saveVariables()

# Create new variables
v2 = manyVariables()
# Check initial values
print(v2.initList[2].numpy())
# [[-1.9110833   0.05956204 -1.1753829  -0.3572553  -0.95049495]
#  [ 0.31409055  1.1262076   0.47890127 -0.1699607   0.4409122 ]
#  [-0.75385517 -0.13847834  0.97012395  0.42515194 -1.4371008 ]
#  [ 0.44205236  0.86158335  0.6919655  -2.5156968   0.16496429]
#  [-1.241602   -0.15177743  0.5603795  -0.3560254  -0.18536267]]
print(v2.initList[3].numpy())
# [[-3.3441594  -0.18425298 -0.4898144  -1.2330629   0.08798431]
#  [ 1.5002227   0.99475247  0.7817361   0.3849587  -0.59548247]
#  [-0.57121766 -1.277224    0.6957546  -0.67618763  0.0510064 ]
#  [ 0.85491985  0.13310803 -0.93152267  0.10205163  0.57520276]
#  [-1.0606447  -0.16966362 -1.0448577   0.56799036 -0.90726566]]

# Restore them
v2.restoreVariables()
# Check values after restoring
print(v2.initList[2].numpy())
# [[-1.9110833   0.05956204 -1.1753829  -0.3572553  -0.95049495]
#  [ 0.31409055  1.1262076   0.47890127 -0.1699607   0.4409122 ]
#  [-0.75385517 -0.13847834  0.97012395  0.42515194 -1.4371008 ]
#  [ 0.44205236  0.86158335  0.6919655  -2.5156968   0.16496429]
#  [-1.241602   -0.15177743  0.5603795  -0.3560254  -0.18536267]]
print(v2.initList[3].numpy())
# [[3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]]
```

If you want to save all the variables in the lists, you could replace `makeCheckpoint` with something like this:

```
def makeCheckpoint(self):
    return tf.train.Checkpoint(
        **{f'init{i}': v for i, v in enumerate(self.initList)},
        **{f'more{i}': v for i, v in enumerate(self.moreList)})
```

Note that you can have "nested" checkpoints so, more generally, you could have a function that makes a checkpoint for a list of variables, for example like this:

```
def listCheckpoint(varList):
    # Use 'item{}'.format(i) if using Python <3.6
    return tf.train.Checkpoint(**{f'item{i}': v for i, v in enumerate(varList)})
```

Then you could just have this:

```
def makeCheckpoint(self):
    return tf.train.Checkpoint(init=listCheckpoint(self.initList),
                               more=listCheckpoint(self.moreList))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man @jdehesa . That is exactly what I wanted. Please also show how to save all of them and restore as this method will not work for many variables. I'll accept your answer then and edit my question suitably so that others can also benefit from it.

Comment: @caissalover I have edited the answer, see if that covers what you were looking for.

Comment: Not quite. This is brute force of the last one. "The easiest way to manage variables is by attaching them to Python objects, then referencing those objects. Subclasses of tf.train.Checkpoint, tf.keras.layers.Layer, and tf.keras.Model automatically track variables assigned to their attributes" In the official doc, creating a checkpoint and giving v1, our object as an argument to it should save it. Still not getting what these guys have done, but something like this should save everything in any manyVariables object. Earlier, it was simpler giving session object to tf.train.Saver

Comment: @caissalover I agree with you that many of the changes seem to be a bit "the Keras way or the highway". It used to be that checkpoints would simply default to save the variables in the collection of global variables, but there are no collections on 2.x, so that's gone. As it says, if you build your stuff around Keras models/layers everything should Just Work™, but if you want to do things differently you are largely on your own. Of course, you can make your own class managing this for you, with overridable methods to create checkpointed variables... which would be repeating what TF/Keras does.

Comment: So then I guess yours is the way to go. I thought making manyVariables a subclass of tf.train.Checkpoint should do something but inheritance is not my thing. I'll stick with your way for now. Without collections of global variables, it's definitely more difficult to save and restore.

Answer (score 2):

In the following code I save an array called variables to a .txt file with a name of your choosing. This file will be in the same folder as your python file. The 'wb' in the open function means write with truncation(so removing everything that was previously in the file) and uses byte format. I use pickle to handle saving/parsing the list.

```
import pickle

    def saveVariables(self, variables): #where 'variables' is a list of variables
        with open("nameOfYourFile.txt", 'wb+') as file:
           pickle.dump(variables, file)

    def retrieveVariables(self, filename):
        variables = []
        with open(str(filename), 'rb') as file:
            variables = pickle.load(file)
        return variables
```

To save specific stuff to your file just add it as the variables argument in saveVariables like so:

```
myVariables = [initList[2], initList[54], initList[59], moreList[3]]
saveVariables(myVariables)
```

To retrieve variables from text file with a certain name:

```
myVariables = retrieveVariables("theNameOfYourFile.txt")
thirdEl = myVariables[0]
fiftyFifthEl = myVariables[1]
SixtiethEl = myVariables[2]
fourthEl = myVariables[3]
```

You could add these functions anywhere in the class.

*To be able to access the initList/moreList in your example however, you should either return them from their functions(like I do with the `variables` list) or make them global.*

Comment: Straightaway, got an error that variables must be a str in file.write(). Was able to save with str(variables) as file.write argument but couldn't load and convert back to tensor. There must be a better method with tf.train.Checkpoint().

Comment: oops you are right there, I forgot to double check that. You could make it work using pickle which allows you to save many formats as byte. I will update the answer. Tensorflow might indeed have an automatic function for this, I have never worked with it so I am not sure.

Comment: That did the job. Thank you very much. Although there should be some tensorflow specific way too so I'll wait a bit more for another answer with tf.train.Checkpoint if possible..